# How to execute tests 50/50 parallel in Selenium Grid

Tags: java, selenium, automation, grid

I have a selenium Grid 3 Set up.
And right now i have 1 hub + 2 nodes. ( 1 local node, one external node).
When i run my test it executes it on local node ( opens 3 browser).

How and where i should set up test execution? If i want to run all tests on 2 browsers, or if i want to run 50/50 tests on 2 browsers?
I will Attached my existing code below.

```
package com.ParallelTest;


        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
        import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

        import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
        import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
        import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class Framework {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Parameters({ "platform","browser","version", "url" })
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setup(String platform, String browser, String
            version, String url) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        driver = getDriverInstance(platform, browser, version, url);

    }

    public static WebDriver getDriverInstance(String platform, String browser, String version, String url)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        String nodeURL = null;

*// IS this should be a Node or Hub path? Because right now it`s a node path. But if i want to use 2 different nodes? How i can implement it????*
        String nodeURL = "http://10.11.161.249:5555/wd/hub";
        WebDriver driver = null;
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        // Platforms
        if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("Windows")) {
            caps.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);


        }
        if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("MAC")) {
            caps.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);

        }
        // Browsers
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/antonfiliptsov/Desktop/Grid/ChromeDriver/chromedriver");
        }
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/antonfiliptsov/Desktop/Grid/Firefox/geckodriver");

        }
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("safari")){
            caps = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
        }

        // Version
        caps.setVersion(version);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), caps);
        // Maximize the browser's window
        // driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Open the Application
        driver.get(url);
        return driver;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Here is my TestNG File

```
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="tests">
    <test name="FireFox Test">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="platform" value="MAC" />
            <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
            <parameter name="version" value="50.1.0" />
            <parameter name="url" value="https://google.com" />
        </parameters>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Chrome Test">
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="platform" value="MAC" />
            <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
            <parameter name="version" value="55.0.2883.87" />
            <parameter name="url" value="https://google.com" />
        </parameters>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.test">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
<test name="Chrome Test 1">
<parameters>
    <parameter name="platform" value="MAC" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="55.0.2883.87" />
    <parameter name="url" value="https://google.com" />
</parameters>
<classes>
    <class name="com.test">
    </class>
</classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

In my test i have **String nodeURL = "http://10.11.161.249:5555/wd/hub";**
Which points my test for specific node, but how i can set up test pointing to to different node, or running parallel on 2 nodes?

Comment: Why would you want to point to different nodes and run tests in parallel ? What are you expecting as a return by doing that ? Your test should be pointing to the Grid URL and NOT the node URL. The grid is agnostic about parallel or sequential execution. As long as there are enough node slots available to run all your parallel tests, all tests will be executed in parallel.

Comment: You mean that if instead of pointing to Node "String nodeURL = "http://10.11.161.249:5555/wd/hub""
I can point to grid  "http://10.11.161.249:4444" and it will run test on all available Node automatically????

Comment: Yes. That's the main purpose of the grid. Let's say you have two nodes each of which can serve 5 sessions, then if your tests start spinning off 6 parallel executions the load will be distributed across both the nodes by the grid ( assuming both the nodes have the same supported capabilities )

Comment: I appreciate your help but can you help me one more time please. 
I am facing an issue and i don't know how to fix it, i tried already a blank project and set up and still having the same issue.
Here is a link for the Logs and my SetUp code:
https://codeshare.io/50YYna
Basically i`m getting a message as 
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{browserName=firefox, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=ANY}]"
And it fails right after launching .xml file. I only changed IP address from node to hub, thats it.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grid is designed to perform the below roles :

- Given a desired capability (something that the test asks for in terms of a browser flavor/version/platform combination), the grid is responsible for running through the list of registered nodes, and matching it to an actual capability.
- Hold excess requests in a queue and then delegate the request to a node as and when it becomes free (when all the nodes are busy)

So you should be pointing your tests to run only against the HUB URL and not against the node URL. The Grid will take care of distributing the tests to the nodes based on the capability matching.

The error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new
>   session cannot find : Capabilities [{browserName=firefox,
>   version=55.0.2883.87, platform=ANY}]

is basically the Grid's way of telling you that, you requested for a `firefox` browser flavour with its version as `55.0.2883.87` running on any platform, but the grid does not have any nodes registered to it that have this capability.

This is rightly so, because your node configuration JSON does not specify version for firefox.

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
            "browserName": "safari",
            "maxInstances": 1,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
    ],
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hub": "http://192.168.1.115:4444",
    "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
    "nodePolling": 5000,
    "role": "node",
    "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
    "downPollingLimit": 2,
    "debug": false,
    "servlets": [

    ],
    "withoutServlets": [

    ],
    "custom": {
    }
}
```

To fix this problem, either

- please remove the line `caps.setVersion(version);` from your `setup()` method (or)
- Enhance your node configuration JSON file to include version number also for firefox.

*Consolidating my responses as an answer.*

Comment: Option with removing somehow didn't worked for me, maybe i missed something there.

But enchanting node configuration helped me, i just added version numbers in the son file, and looks like it`s running OK. 

Thank you!